# Mandatory participation vs. random assignment

Tags: repeated-measures, sampling

Can I make a statistical inference about the effect of a training intervention on a population of employees if participants are not randomly assigned to participate in the training but required to participate? Participation would not likely be 100% but at least 90% and it's anticipated non-participation would be random. Would a repeated measures design be appropriate in this situation, e.g., a paired samples t-test, repeated measures ANOVA or ANCOVA with the pre-test as a covariate to test for differences between fixed factors such as region or department?

Comment: If you really do have the entire population of interest, statistical testing is of no relevance: just look at the results. In practice this situation is *extremely* rare; if nothing else, the results of a test have some variation that is best attributed to chance. At a minimum, your "population" thereby becomes the set of *all possible sets of pre-post test results;* your data are a sample of that population; and your target of inference concerns properties of the subjects you tested *as they were at the time of the test.* But don't you want to infer something about *the intervention* itself?

Comment: Yes the effect of the intervention on the assessment is the issue. I'm fairly confident that not every single person will end up participating in the training but by design that's what's intended for implementation. Additionally, a certain percentage (small) will not complete the assessments. Even if there were 100% participation, could I assume that the inference would be about a future population of employees?

Comment: It's not an assumption--it's an *intention.* You get to determine why you are obtaining and analyzing these data and you get to choose what inferences you want to make. Those in turn will indicate what population (or process) you should think of the data as representing. (Whether, and how well, they represent the population of interest is another question that is addressed by considering how the subjects were selected from that population.) That's why I commented before: if you realize that you want to make inferences about this intervention in the future, you need to let us know.

Comment: Ok thank you for clarifying that. I want to be able to make an inference about the effectiveness of this training for this population of employees as well as a future population of employees in the same role (controling for the same factors and incvluding the pre-test results as a covariate. Could I use a repeated measures ANOVA or ANCOVA to do this without random assigment?

Comment: The best thing to do now is to edit your question to reflect this change in perspective--few readers will want to wade through these comments.  Then sit back and see what kinds of answers you get!